# how to create a option switch which will take multiple values?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have used option attribute, which takes value from command line and passed it to the object of Options class.
Consider if I pass : -j 23
then it will set 23 to JournalId property. But I want to make changes in my code such that If I pass : -j 23 2016 5 as values
then it must assign 23 to JournalId, 2016 to Year and 5 to IssueId accordingly.
So, what changes I have to make in my code to make it possible

```
class Options
{

    [Option('j',"journalid", Required = true,
      HelpText = "journal Id.")]
    public int JournalId { get; set; }


    [Option("year", DefaultValue = 0,
      HelpText = "Publication year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Option("issueId", DefaultValue = 0,
      HelpText = "Publication IssueId")]
    public int IssueId { get; set; }

    [ParserState]
    public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

    [HelpOption('h')]
    public string GetUsage() 
    {
        return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
          (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
    }
}

// Consume them
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var options = new Options();


    if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options))
    {
        // Values are available here
        if (true) Console.WriteLine("JournalId: {0} {1} {2}", options.JournalId,options.Year,options.IssueId);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need some flexibility in how Options objects are initialized.  By inializing them with attributes, you are constrained to modifying the Options class itself in order to change how it is initialized.  Instead of using attributes, you might want to consider using one of the classic [creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern), such as a Factory.

For example, your factory class would take the command line arguments and parse them. It would have a public method that constructs an Options object and initializes it based on the results of the command line parsing.

When you need to modify how the command line is parsed, you either modify the factory class or write a new factory class with the same interface.